# MongoDB условие по списоку данных

Tags: mongodb, массивы, выборка

Подскажите как реализовать такую выборку и возможно ли это сделать.
Вкратце: 
Есть список ID (массив) нужно по массиву значений найти все записи в коллекции.

Подробно:
Есть переменная array содержит список ID

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Есть коллекция collection в которой содержаться записи вида:

```
{ 
"id" : 801, 
"level" : 6,
    ......
}
```

Нужно выбрать все записи с id переданные в array, а так же с условием что level = 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({ "id" : { "$in" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] }, "level" : 6 })
```

Comment: блин, все так просто после sql баз =)

Comment: @webphp да и в sql это простой запрос